# Изменение переменной Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Можно ли как то сделать так, чтобы при клике по кнопке на сайте менялась переменная. Пишу сайт через Flask на питоне.

```
<a href="/1"  class="btn btn-dark">1</a>
```

К примеру есть эта кнопка и есть переменная `x`. Мне нужно, чтобы при срабатывании кнопки она выполняла действие `x+=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшой рабочий пример для изменения значения поля `input`. По нажатию кнопки значение увеличивается на 1.

```
from flask import Flask, request

def my_count(x):
    x+=1
    return str(x)

app = Flask(__name__)

nav = '''
    <a href="/">Главная</a>
    <a href="/counter">Счетчик</a>
    <hr>
'''


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return nav

@app.route('/counter', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def rand():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # return 'POST'
        char_x = request.form['my_var']
        int_x = int(char_x)
        my_var = my_count(int_x)
        return nav +  f'''
            <form action="/rand" method="post">
                <input name='my_var' value="{my_var}" readonly="true">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            '''
    else:
        # return 'GET'
        return nav  + '''
            <form action="/rand" method="post">
                <input name='my_var' value="0" readonly="true">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
            '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: @insolor ну да, надо было назвать по-другому, поправил