# Получить значение переменных из javascript или html

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Я использую flask для создания будильника с web интерфейсом. Я создал вот такой html код:

```
<!-- (A) CURRENT TIME -->
<div id="ctime">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/js-alarm-clock.css') }}"> >
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js-alarm-clock.js') }}"></script>
  <h1 class="header">THE CURRENT TIME</h1>
  <div class="square">
    <div class="digits" id="chr">00</div>
    <div class="text">HR</div>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <div class="digits" id="cmin">00</div>
    <div class="text">MIN</div>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <div class="digits" id="csec">00</div>
    <div class="text">SEC</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- (B) SET ALARM -->
<div id="tpick">
  <h1 class="header">
    SET ALARM
  </h1>
  <div id="tpick-h"></div>
  <div id="tpick-m"></div>
  <div id="tpick-s"></div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Set" id="tset"/>
    <input type="button" value="Reset" id="treset" disabled/>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- (C) ALARM SOUND -->
<audio id="alarm-sound" loop>
  <source src="wake-up-sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Также я сделал javascript

```
var ac = {
  init : function () {
  // ac.init() : start the alarm clock

    // Get the current time - hour, min, seconds
    ac.chr = document.getElementById("chr");
    ac.cmin = document.getElementById("cmin");
    ac.csec = document.getElementById("csec");

    // The time picker - Hr, Min, Sec
    ac.thr = ac.createSel(23);
    document.getElementById("tpick-h").appendChild(ac.thr);
    ac.thm = ac.createSel(59);
    document.getElementById("tpick-m").appendChild(ac.thm);
    ac.ths = ac.createSel(59);
    document.getElementById("tpick-s").appendChild(ac.ths);

    // The time picker - Set, reset
    ac.tset = document.getElementById("tset");
    ac.tset.addEventListener("click", ac.set);
    ac.treset = document.getElementById("treset");
    ac.treset.addEventListener("click", ac.reset);

    // The alarm sound
    ac.sound = document.getElementById("alarm-sound");

    // Start the clock
    ac.alarm = null;
    setInterval(ac.tick, 1000);
  },

  createSel : function (max) {
  // createSel() : support function - creates a selector for hr, min, sec

    var selector = document.createElement("select");
    for (var i=0; i<=max; i++) {
      var opt = document.createElement("option");
      i = ac.padzero(i);
      opt.value = i;
      opt.innerHTML = i;
      selector.appendChild(opt);
    }
    return selector
  },

  padzero : function (num) {
  // ac.padzero() : support function - pads hr, min, sec with 0 if <10

    if (num < 10) { num = "0" + num; }
    else { num = num.toString(); }
    return num;
  },

  tick : function () {
  // ac.tick() : update the current time

    // Current time
    var now = new Date();
    var hr = ac.padzero(now.getHours());
    var min = ac.padzero(now.getMinutes());
    var sec = ac.padzero(now.getSeconds());

    // Update current clock
    ac.chr.innerHTML = hr;
    ac.cmin.innerHTML = min;
    ac.csec.innerHTML = sec;

    // Check and sound alarm
    if (ac.alarm != null) {
      now = hr + min + sec;
      if (now == ac.alarm) {
        if (ac.sound.paused) {
          ac.sound.play();
        }
      }
    }
  },

  set : function () {
  // ac.set() : set the alarm

    ac.alarm = ac.thr.value + ac.thm.value + ac.ths.value;
    ac.thr.disabled = true;
    ac.thm.disabled = true;
    ac.ths.disabled = true;
    ac.tset.disabled = true;
    ac.treset.disabled = false;
  },

  reset : function () {
  // ac.reset() : reset the alarm

    if (!ac.sound.paused) {
      ac.sound.pause();
    }
    ac.alarm = null;
    ac.thr.disabled = false;
    ac.thm.disabled = false;
    ac.ths.disabled = false;
    ac.tset.disabled = false;
    ac.treset.disabled = true;
  }
};

// INIT - RUN ALARM CLOCK
window.addEventListener("load", ac.init);
```

И также я сделал функция во flask, чтобы при переходе по ссылке можно было бы поставить будильник. У меня вопрос, как я могу в питоне получить время, которое поставил пользователь, нажав кнопку set?

Comment: а время должно быть именно в секции `<div>` нельзя использовать `input`

Comment: Нужно именно списком выбор давать

Comment: ну так в инпут же тоже можно селект передать

Comment: Да? А можете тогда, пожалуйста, пример такой для часов привести и как из питон его взять?

Comment: Я не очень силен в js, но по идее вы же можете передать все 3 значения в скрытый инпут, добавить все инпуты в форму, ей добавить метод пост с каким-нибудь name и обработать метод пост как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206901/Изменение-переменной-flask/1206929#1206929